Potential of circle and $n$-gon
Consider power central fields $f \sim r^k, - \infty < k <  \infty$,
and unit circle, "charged" in the sense of the field.
We will be interested in the potential within the circle,
i.e. scalar sum or integral.
The potential $\psi$ of a  charge or small element will also be a power,
except $f \sim r^{-1}$, then $\psi \sim \ln (r)$
Var 1.  The charge is distributed continuously.
It is known that for $f \sim r^{-2},  \psi \sim r^{-1}$ the force acting on the test charge inside the spheres are $0$ and the potential is constant.
This is proved not only by Gauss’s theorem,
but also through the consideration of sites cut out by opposite bodily angles.
In the case of circle and other powers I find it difficult to apply the integral theorems.
Applying the idea of angles and arcs, it turns out that for $f \sim r^{-1},  \psi \sim \ln (r)$
the full potential inside the circle must be constant, and this is confirmed by the trial
by calculations.
Question 1.1  How to prove it?
Question 1.2 Are there other central fields, perhaps not power law,
for which the potential inside the circle is constant?
Var 2. If we replace the circle with a right $n$-gon, the angle dependence appears.
But not always! As revealed intuitively, and now proven:
If $k = 2 d > 0$, the potential does not depend on the angle at $d < n$
Question 2.1 Can the linked reasoning be generalised and supplemented (eg for $k<0$)?
Question 2.2 Even in cases of other $k>0$, the potential dependence on the angle is very weak.
For example, at $k = 1, n = 3$ and moving the test charge around a radius of $0.5$
potential varies within $3.14 <  \psi < 3.23$
And for $n = 4$ $4.23 <  \psi < 4.25$
No "approximation" of a circle by a triangle and a square can be said.
So why this is so?

Obviously $k=0$ is also a solution for constant potential, so if you don't rule that out your solution with any other $k$ cannot be unique...
